# (Ruby) Converting a string to a line of code?

Tags: ruby, string, text, conditional-statements

So, for a game I'm working on, let's say I put a bit of text in the comment box of a spell:

`<secondary effects: [["Flame", 15, true], ["Poison", 0.08, true]]>`

By using the slice feature, I can reduce the text down to:

`[["Flame", 15, true], ["Poison", 0.08, true]]`

and then store it in the `data` variable, so

`data = "[["Flame", 15, true], ["Poison, 0.08, true]]"`

Now, how could I convert this text into code, so I could make a condition during the spell's damage process such as:

`if data[0][2] == true then *something* end`

Obviously, I can't use `eval` on the text in order to make it into data.

Answer (score 3):

You example is a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) conform string (after fixing the missing `"`). Therefore I would just use a [`JSON.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse):

```
string = '[["Flame", 15, true], ["Poison", 0.08, true]]'
#=> "[[\"Flame\", 15, true], [\"Poison\", 0.08, true]]"

require 'json'
JSON.parse(string)
#=> [["Flame", 15, true], ["Poison", 0.08, true]]
```

Comment: This is the answer. Use a data language for data.

Comment: When I test this out in tutorialspoint dot com's execution test, this process works, but with the program I'm using, RPGMakerVXAce, it says 'No such file found' for json. When I read up on it, JSON is a JavaScript language interpreter, but in later years has been used in multiple programming languages. Perhaps this program uses an earlier version of Ruby, or it simply isn't included?

Comment: What version of Ruby do you use? Call `ruby -v` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a very simple and quick solution.

```
data = eval('[["Flame", 15, true], ["Poison", 0.08, true]]')
```

Please make sure Flame has two quotes surrounding it but Poison don't. If it's a typo then above will work as it is but if not the case then you will need to add appropriate quotes to the any given string.

If you do not want to use eval then you can do something like below.

```
'[["Flame", 15, true], ["Poison", 0.08, true]]'.gsub(/[\[\]]/,'').split(",").each_slice(3).to_a
```

Comment: Suggesting `eval` without a warning about its usage isn't a good idea. Image when someone enters `rm -rf /` into that box...

Comment: Suggesting only convert your string to not the whole code. But if that is the case you can use something like this '[["Flame", 15, true], ["Poison", 0.08, true]]'.gsub(/[\[\]]/,'').split(",").each_slice(3).to_a , you can make solution more dynamic as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Whole idea of putting data into comments in Ruby is a smell. But first, let me literally answer your question: Any string *is* a code line in Ruby. To see whether it's a *valid* line, you just `eval` it:

```
string = "[{foo: 1}, {bar: 2}]"
data = eval string
data[0][:foo] #=> 1
```

Instead of trying to stuff code into comments, in Ruby we usually try to do the opposite: Stuff comments into code. More precisely, to write self-explanatory code that can be understood without comments. We call it literate programming.